# problems with JWT Authentication using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up JWT Authentication

I've been following this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-jwt-authorization-and-authentication-in-spring/

I can successfully create new user, problems start when I try to log in......

I keep getting response status 403 Forbidden

JWTAuthenticationFilter

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
    import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
    import com.example.flashcards.entities.UserEntity;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    
    public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
        public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    
            setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
        }
    
        u/Override
        public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                throws AuthenticationException {
            
            System.out.println(req);
            try {
                
                
                UserEntity creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), UserEntity.class);
                
                System.out.println(creds);
    
                return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    
        u/Override
        protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
                Authentication auth) throws IOException {
            String token = JWT.create().withSubject(((UserEntity) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                    .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                    .sign(Algorithm.HMAC512(SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes()));
    
            String body = ((UserEntity) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername() + " " + token;
            
            System.out.println(body);
    
            res.getWriter().write(body);
            res.getWriter().flush();
        }
    }
```

JWTAuthorizationFilter

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;

public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    u/Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    // Reads the JWT from the Authorization header, and then uses JWT to validate
    // the token
    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);

        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes())).build()
                    .verify(token.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, "")).getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                // new arraylist means authorities
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }

            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

WebSecurity

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

u/SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
u/EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsService userService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    u/Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers( HttpMethod.POST, "/users/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    u/Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    u/Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

UserController

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.flashcards.entities.UserEntity;
import com.example.flashcards.repositories.UserRepository;

u/CrossOrigin
u/RestController
u/RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    u/Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    // u/Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    u/PostMapping("/new")
    public Long saveUser(@RequestBody UserEntity user) {
        UserEntity newUser = user;
        newUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        return userRepo.save(newUser).getUserId();
    }

}
```

when I send POST request with JSON body with user info to `http://localhost:8080/users/new` everything is peachy, new user gets created and saved to database

when I send POST request with JSON body with username and password to `http://localhost:8080/login` I keep getting `403 Forbidden`

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

I'm a beginner and this is my very first time dealing with Spring Security.

Comment: you should permit url 'http://localhost:8080/login ' in web security config. Try something like this: `.antMatchers( "/login/**").permitAll()`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the hint ;)

I got it to work now. The problem was that in `JWTAuthenticationFilter`, in `successfulAuthentication` method I was trying to use my `UserEntity` when it was supposed to be `User` from Spring's `UserServiceDetail` once I made that change it started working :)